# How to retrieve the latest eventName (latest by date)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, user-interface

I have two arrays

```
var events=["DELIVERED", "OUT TO DELEVERY", "REACHED WAREHOUSE", "DEPARTED"];

var eventDetails= [{
"source" : "application"
"DateTime": "2016-05-12 11:20:00",
"eventName" : "DELIVERED"
},
{
"source" : "application"
"DateTime": "2017-06-07 00:00:00",
"eventName" : "OUT TO DELEVERY"
},
{
"source" : "application"
"DateTime": "2016-11-05 11:20:00",
"eventNname" : "CUSTOM CLEARANCE"
}];
```

I need to display the latest eventName (latest by date and time) from eventDetails array, if the latest eventName is present in "events" Array. Else it should return null( if eventName in latest updated record doesn't contain any of the value from event array).

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a few different ways. A simple solution to this would be sorting the events by date and then grabbing the one you need (the first in this case):

```
var eventDetails= [{
  "source" : "application",
  "DateTime": "2016-05-12 11:20:00",
  "eventName" : "DELIVERED"
}, {
  "source" : "application",
  "DateTime": "2017-06-07 00:00:00",
  "eventName" : "OUT TO DELEVERY"
}, {
  "source" : "application",
  "DateTime": "2016-11-05 11:20:00",
  "eventNname" : "CUSTOM CLEARANCE"
}];

var last = eventDetails.sort(function(prev, next) {
    return new Date(next.DateTime) - new Date(prev.DateTime);
})[0];

var lastEventName = last.eventName;

if (events.indexOf(lastEventName) >= 0) {
  // Return true
} else {
  // Return false
}
```

### Option 2:

You can also loop through all events and keep track of the latest:

```
var last = eventDetails[0];
for (var i = 1; i < eventDetails.length; i++) {
  if (eventDetails[i].DateTime > last.DateTime) {
    last = eventDetails[i];
  }
}
var lastEventName = last.eventName;

if (events.indexOf(lastEventName) >= 0) {
  // Return true
} else {
  // Return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Implemented the same code :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript `sort` method and use `indexOf` to check the value is exist in the `events` array

```js
var events=["DELIVERED", "REACHED WAREHOUSE", "OUT TO DELEVERY", "DEPARTED"];

var eventDetails= [{
"source" : "application",
"DateTime": "2016-05-12 11:20:00",
"eventName" : "DELIVERED"
},
{
"source" : "application",
"DateTime": "2017-06-07 00:00:00",
"eventName" : "OUT TO DELEVERY"
},
{
"source" : "application",
"DateTime": "2016-11-05 11:20:00",
"eventName" : "CUSTOM CLEARANCE"
}];

eventDetails = eventDetails.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.DateTime) - new Date(a.DateTime)
})
 
if( events.indexOf(eventDetails[0].eventName) !== -1 ){ 
  console.log('true')
}else{
 console.log('false')
}
```